# How to test whether an expression is a valid variable?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I would like to test whether an argument is a valid variable for functions like `Solve` and `DSolve`.  For instance several functions generate a [`"dsvar"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/DSolve/dsvar.html) or [`"ivar"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/General/ivar.html) message on bad input:

> DSolve::dsvar: 2 x cannot be used as a variable. >>
>   Integrate::ivar: Sin[x] is not a valid variable. >>

I would like to check an argument before passing it onto one of these functions.

I used the function `withBlockedVars` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32780/extracting-variables-from-hold-expression/32791#32791) to come up with what seems like a maybe-not-very-bad way.  I block the variable and attempt to assign a value to it.

```
ClearAll[withBlockedVars];
SetAttributes[withBlockedVars, HoldRest];
withBlockedVars[Hold[expr_], code_] :=
 With[{heldVars =
    Thread[Cases[Unevaluated[expr],
        s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global`" && DownValues[s] === {} :> HoldComplete[s],
        Infinity,
        Heads -> True],
     HoldComplete]},
  heldVars /. HoldComplete[vars_List] :> Block[vars, code]]


SetAttributes[variableQ, HoldAll];
variableQ[x_] := withBlockedVars[Hold[x], Quiet@Check[x = 0; True, False]];
```

Tests:

```
t = 2;
variableQ[2^t]
(* False *)

t = 2; x = 3;
variableQ[x[2^t]]
(* True *)

variableQ[t[2]]
(* True *)

variableQ[Subscript[t, 2]]
(* True *)
```

My use-case is for defining functions, something like this:

```
f[eqn_Equal, var_?variableQ] := code
```

The `code` might call `NDSolve` or `Plot` and so on.

Is there a better way to check `var`? Perhaps there is a built-in function I missed?

[*Edit:* Any solution involving `Pattern`, `PatternTest`, `Condition` etc. would be acceptable.  I'm not sure I can think of all the alternative possibilities.]

Comment: I thought perhaps "bulletproofing" or "package-writing" might be a good tag, but I found none similar.

Comment: Are you looking for another `variableQ` or are you OK with alternate approaches?

Comment: @rm-rf I'm ok with alternate approaches.

Comment: If you define a variable as an expression which can be assigned a value (is an L-value), then the test based on `Block` alone will miss some cases, e.g. `Protected` symbols.

Comment: What about using the built-in checks? Something like `variableQ[var_] := 
 Quiet[Check[Solve[0, var]~Quiet~Solve::naqs; True, False, 
   Solve::ivar], Solve::ivar]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that for the basic case described in the question it would be best to simply check if a System function considers it valid, as I did for [Pattern that matches colors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/pattern-that-matches-colors/15434#15434).  Therefore:

```
variableQ = Quiet @ ListQ @ Solve[{}, #] &;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I like this (similar to Rojo's comment above).  The problem is for me that the requirements of the functions mentioned in the question, `Solve`, `DSolve`, `Plot`, etc., are different.  And I don't think I fully appreciated the differences when I posed the question.  For instance, `Plot` tries to use something like `Set` on the plot variable.  So while `{E[1], D[x], x[1]}` all pass your `variableQ` but only `x[1]` works with `Plot`.  `Solve` seems very forgiving of what sort of expression may be used as a variable: `Solve[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]^2 == 4, Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Perhaps a separate test for each kind of function? (`solveVariableQ` etc.)  Or how about using the Message itself to check for the error?  Would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: Perhaps a `plotVariableQ` would be the most restrictive and would work for the other functions. `Plot[0, {var, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 0]` is quick to fail and not too slow to succeed. I wanted to avoid a long computation that ends in a message that the input was invalid. For instance a long `(N)DSolve` followed by `Plot`. Perhaps my `withBlockedVars` method is ok? (My Q really was a generalization based on the observation that *M* checks for valid variables for some alg./calc. functions. In the case of `Plot` it does it early.)

Comment: This seems good: `variableQ = Quiet@Check[Table[0, {#, 1}]; True, False] &`  - what do you think?  It's fast to fail or succeed and it tries to write the variable, like `Plot`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Table` is no good for your purpose because it does not respect `Protected` on bare Symbols, e.g.: `Table[E, {E, 1}]`.  (Enigmatically it complains with `E[1]`.)  Then again `Plot` accepts input such as `Plot[E, {E, 0, 15}]` without issuing a message but doesn't work properly, yielding a flat line.  Does your original method return the correct `True`/`False` for *all* cases?  If so I can base a method on those results.

Comment: Actually, no, not on all the cases I've come up with.  I had to change the last line of `withBlockedVars` to `heldVars /. HoldComplete[vars_List] :> Block[vars, code] /. {} -> Block[{}, code]` to handle `E`, `E[1]`, etc. (where `Cases` returns an empty list).  Then it works.

Comment: Thanks.  This answers the question, although I often follow rm-rf's example.  (I must have gotten busy and forgotten this Q until I wanted to check it.)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a `variableQ`, how about constraining `var` to be a `Symbol`, giving your function the `HoldAll` attribute and then `Block`ing the variable? I use this idiom/pattern all the time. As an example:

```
Clear@f
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[expr_, var_Symbol] := Block[{var}, Solve[expr, var] /. var -> Defer@var]
f[expr_, var_[n___]] := Block[{var}, f[expr /. var[n] -> var, var] /. var -> var@n]
```

Now try the following:

```
x = 1;
f[x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]
(* {{x -> -1}, {x -> -1}} *)

a[1] = 2;
f[a[1]^2 + 2 a[1] + 1 == 0, a[1]]
(* {{a[1] -> -1}, {a[1] -> -1}} *)
```

No `ivar` error. This also takes care of cases like `x^2` or `2 x`, because these are not `Symbol`s.

Comment: You don't have to use `Block` - if the symbol evaluates, it is not a valid variable (does not match `_Symbol` any more) :). Otherwise, that's what I'd also do - +1.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The `Block` takes care of cases where there might be stray assignments in Global that you don't want evaluating inside the body. (for instance, in my example above, removing the `Block` will give you an `ivar` error) Given Michael's use case, I suspect this would be a desirable option.

Comment: I see. As an alternative, you could simply use `HoldFirst`, and omit the `Block`. But I agree, you construct is generally more useful, and this is also what I usually do.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of, too, mainly for simplicity (for myself).  But I'm writing it for students and I anticipate their wanting to do things their own way and having "stray assigments" about.  We also will have systems and I wondered if it would be hard to handle `x[1]` etc.  If I do it this way, I could write my own error message. +1

Comment: @MichaelE2 `x[1]` can be handled with a second definition: `f[expr_, var_[n___]] := 
 Block[{var}, f[expr /. var[n] -> var, var] /. var -> var@n]`.

Comment: Since expressions contained in `Defer` cannot be easily used programmatically I do not anticipate using this construct.  In fact I would find it confusing for this to fail:  `a[1] = 2; r = f[a[1]^2 + 2 a[1] + 1 == 0, a[1]];  ClearAll[a]; a[1] /. r`, meaning that it returns:

`{{a[1] -> -1}, {a[1] -> -1}}` and `{a[1], a[1]}`.  One could replace `Defer` with `HoldPattern` which would give this output for the same input:  `{{HoldPattern[a[1]] -> -1}, {HoldPattern[a[1]] -> -1}}` and `{-1, -1}` but that is hardly clean.  What utility do you see in this construct?