# Method for determining valid name syntax?

Tags: syntax, symbols

This question [40194](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40194/how-to-test-whether-an-expression-is-a-valid-variable) asks about work arounds to check and replace variable names which are invalid in a specific MMA function context. For that case testing using the function itself is the most reliable approach, but I'd like a more general method.

Is there a builtin function or a more general way to test syntax and validity?

One idea, if there are error messages, we can use `Check`:

```
varCheckQ[s_String]:=Check[SyntaxQ[Symbol[s]], False] // Quiet

varCheckQ/@{"1st","two wrds","no_good","al.most","ok"}
(* {False, False, False, False, True} *)
```

Or, maybe try to match with unevaluated

```
varNameQ[s_String]:=!BooleanQ[Quiet@Symbol[s]==Unevaluated@Symbol[s]]

varNameQ/@{"1st","two wrds","no_good","al.most","ok"}
(* {False, False, False, False, True} *)
```

These work, but don't seem very robust. Is there a utility function defined somewhere that already does this using MMA's rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the undocumented function `` Internal`SymbolNameQ ``:

```
Internal`SymbolNameQ /@ {"1st", "two wrds", "no_good", "al.most", "ok"}
```

> ```
>  {False, False, False, False, True}
> ```

Comment: Internal`SymbolNameQ: Undocumented function that apparently identifies a string as a "symbol name."