# What sorts of expressions can be Solve'd for?

Tags: equation-solving, pattern-matching, symbols, internals

We can `Solve` for expressions that match `_Symbol`, as in `Solve[x^2+1 == 0, x]`—but we can also solve for more general expressions, such as `x[1]` (`Solve[x[1]^2+1 == 0, x[1]]`) and `Subscript`s (`Solve[Subscript[x, 1]^2+1 == 0, Subscript[x, 1]]`). However, not every expression can be a variable for `Solve`: `Solve["a"^2+1 == 0, "a"]` returns the `Solve::ivar` error message, saying that `"a"` is not a valid variable.

So, what makes an expression a "valid variable" in the sense of `Solve` internally?

Is it related to what expressions can hold definitions, or is that a separate question?

A workaround can be obtained, in a similar manner to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40194/how-to-test-whether-an-expression-is-a-valid-variable), by testing a simple `Solve` for the error message directly:

```
VariableQ[expr_] := 
 Quiet[Check[Solve[True, expr]; True, False, {Solve::ivar}], {Solve::ivar}]
```

but I'd like to understand the logic behind what is or isn't a valid variable.